# Cloud foundry datasource timeout oracle JDBC why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a cloud setup in **Pivotal** and i have **Database connection pool** but the request for database gets **timed out**.
I have used **cloudfoundry** to setup the connection using **spring boot**.

What are the things i should look for in code to **trace the problem**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Database Connection Pool"? What do you mean by it?
Did you create one? How did you inject it in the PaaS?

In PCF, you create a user-provided-service (CUPS) for databases outside of the PCF. You will have to create a service instance of the CUPS and bind it to your app.

The PaaS manage the rest of the details. In your app define a datasource, which will be injected by the PaaS into your App at runtime.

Look at the Spring Music app and its documentation on how to use Spring Boot app with a database.

Comment: Thanks @aksX for the answer but my issue is already resolved it was because of the bad ldap url

Comment: Hello, @askX I defined my datasource values in application.properties. My Application works fine locally, But when I push it to cloud foundry, I receive timeout error. status = 500

Comment: Jesse, 
I think you should start with [12 Factor Principles for Cloud Native Apps](https://12factor.net/). Please pay attention to externalization of resources.

This [link](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/gsg-spring.html) will give you basics of services and how you inject them into cloud environment.